# How do I append a line to all .gitignore files recursively?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, tee

I have a directory that have multiple subdirectories with git repositories. I want to add `desktop.ini` to all `.gitignore` files in these subdirectories.

I know i can do `echo "desktop.ini" | tee -a .gitignore`, but it does not work recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, enabled recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then do:

```
echo "desktop.ini" | tee -a **/.gitignore
```

Comment: Perfect idea! worked for me :)

Comment: The only issue is that when there's a lot of files matching the regex **/.gitignore, a warning says "Too many open files". Do you know how to come over that?

Comment: @AhmedHussein you could do use a shell loop: `for i in **/.gitignore; do echo desktop.ini >> "$i"; done`